# Get ggplot variable from active device

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

is there a way to get back the actual ggplot variable from a plot ? Here is a MWE of what I'd like to achieve:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
print(p)
rm(p)
```

How could I get back `p` considering the fact that the device is still on and active ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ggplot2 package covers a function

[last_plot()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/last_plot.html)

```
p <- last_plot()
```